# Is it possible to simulate a bus topology in mininet?

Tags: mininet

Can Mininet support a bus topology, where there are more than 2 endpoints on a single link?  I have been asked to create a topology file for a network diagram that I have been given and it shows two switches and a host all sharing the same link.

Comment: Turns out they wanted me to 'simulate' a bus topology using some level 2 legacy switches that are not open flow enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible with Mininet.
The only thing that is similar to a bus topology is the Linear topology, as mentioned here [reference](https://books.google.fr/books?id=TEvYDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA132&lpg=PA132&dq=bus%20topology%20mininet&source=bl&ots=4NZPLxCNbL&sig=ACfU3U1FOjqWdlxPjdXTEDYGwUEI2dz85Q&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwihr5bjosPqAhWMERQKHWd1D5IQ6AEwFnoECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q=bus%20topology%20mininet&f=false).

But you have n switches and n hosts.